# Is there a way to Extract attachment from Email Message Mime Content without using Exchange Service?

Tags: c#, parsing, exchangewebservices, email-attachments, eml

I am having a client application which will save eml files to the local disk. Need to get the attachment inside the eml file which is saved without using the exchange service because the Mailbox keeps changing of its capacity.Please help if anyone have come across similar issue

I have tried the reverse process of getting the eml file and load it again to get the details.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [MimeKit](http://www.mimekit.net/#about) for this. The [GitHub](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) page has examples on how to parse MIME messages and how to get attachments.

Here is an example of how to get the attachments in an array of bytes:

```
var mimeMessage = MimeMessage.Load(@"test.eml");
var attachments = mimeMessage.Attachments.ToList();

foreach (var attachment in attachments)
{
    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        if (attachment is MimePart)
            ((MimePart)attachment).Content.DecodeTo(memory);
        else
            ((MessagePart)attachment).Message.WriteTo(memory);

        var bytes = memory.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will check it out MadDev.. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I checked the code. I have an email with an eml file itself as an attachment. In this the case the code is not able to get the attachment. Is there anything I missed out above? mimeMessage.Attachments.ToList(); the count is 0.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Big Thanks to MadDev for helping out !!!

Here is the Code which I used:

Note: Here in case, the stored email will always have another eml file attached to it and this is based on the business logic.

```
    protected static void MimeProcessor(MemoryStream stream)
    {

        try
        {
            var parser = new MimeParser(stream, MimeFormat.Default);
            var message = parser.ParseMessage();
            var multipart = message.Body as Multipart;
            //Found the Attachment as Message Part
            var OriginalMessage = multipart.ToList().LastOrDefault();
            if (OriginalMessage is MessagePart)
            {
                using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ((MessagePart)OriginalMessage).Message.WriteTo(memory);
                    var bytes = memory.ToArray();
                    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Test\\TestMessage.eml", bytes);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```